# Vertically align a navbar-brand with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I align a navar-brand img vertically in the middle?

[image]

That black box is a logo I want to align in the middle.

The markup is:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>

    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img alt="Brand" width="163" height="36" src="...">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You can try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/342/

Answer (score 1):

just add this to your css :

```
.navbar-brand{
    min-height: 66px !important;
}
.navbar-header{
    min-height: 66px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the css property 'vertical-align: top;'? If it doesnt work try positioning it relatively and see for yourself if it's perfectly align.