# Vertical align logo inside .navbar-brand with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3.3.7

I have the following markup:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            Company Name <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/220x36">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

All I'm trying to do is get the logo image to appear vertically centre inside `.navbar-brand`

Instead it renders like this:

[image]

I want it to render like this:

[image]

The only way I could make it look how I wanted is by applying hacky CSS:

```
img {
    margin-top:-7.5px; 
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/swzj0uk0/1/

I've had a look at [Vertically align a navbar-brand with bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34237002/vertically-align-a-navbar-brand-with-bootstrap) and various other posts on vertical alignment.

Some posts have suggested setting a `height:` attribute on `.navbar`. I don't understand why that would be necessary because the default navbar height is 50px and my image is only 36px high.

Please can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some custom style and set `display: flex` and `align-items: center` on `navbar-brand` element.

```css
.navbar-brand {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
         Company Name <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/220x36">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```